# Absolute Value in an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a problem that asks for the $\int_3^8 |g(x)| {\rm d}x$. Instead of a value given for $g(x)$ I was given a graph and told to figure it out geometrically.
Does the absolute value sign mean that I first add all the values and then take the absolute value or do I first take the absolute value and then add?
The difference would be when the $g(x)$ goes below the $x$-axis and I have both positive and negative values.

Comment: Note, $|g(x)| \geq 0$ for all $x$, so is the area under $|g(x)|$ ever negative? Furthermore, what does $|g(x)|$ actually mean? Perhaps it would be clearer for you if you think in terms of the definition of the absolute value. $|g(x)| = g(x)$ for $g(x) \geq 0$ and $|g(x)| = -g(x)$ for $g(x)<0$.

Comment: So I should first take the absolute value of everything.

Comment: The graph I was given has negatives. Does that not make sense?

Comment: To translate my earlier jargon, looking geometrically at your given graph, just reflect the negative parts of $g(x)$ over the $x$ axis and integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\int_3^8 |g(x)| {\rm d}x$, the value which you are integrating is $|g(x)|$. As Hendrix says in a comment, this is always non-negative. As such, based on what integration means, you need to always take the absolute values of anything you're using first and then add those over the region of integration, i.e., $3$ to $8$.

Doing it the other way around would give you the wrong answer if you subtract any values (in particular, the result would be too small). Note doing this would be equivalent to solving $|\int_3^8 g(x) {\rm d}x|$ instead.